# Laravel - get all records that contains a specific string

Tags: php, laravel, pagination

I'm trying to get a query that gives me every record that contains a specific string in a specific column( no matter if the first letter is uppercase or lowercase.

For example: The string I'm passing is test

And I have 30 records in my database. 5 of them have do contain test ( lowercase ) and 5 of them Test ( uppercase ) . The 20 other records are useless, so I don't need them.

I've got some help yesterday but couldn't make it like I really want it and the output is also wrong.

Thats the code:

```
$search = $request['search'];
        $usergroups = Usergroups::where('name', 'like', '%' . str_slug($search, ' ') . '%')->simplePaginate(3);
```

$search is a variable that contains the string I want to search for.

If I want to search for Test, I get just every record back. No matter if it contains Test, test, or unicorn bla bla. I get just everything back.

Does someone knows a way to fix that? I've tried to write a custom paginate class but that haven't worked for me.

[image]

Comment: Why use `orWhere` without `where`?

Comment: Use `where` and also go for `str_slug` laravel function for more connivance.

Comment: let me try this.

Comment: okay I've changed it to where and used str_slug like this: `:where('name', 'like', '%' . str_slug($search, ' ') . '%')` - But this haven't helped. I still get everything back

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not so sure but I think there is an error with the class. If I output $usergroups I get this:

```
current_page    1
data: 
   // my data 
from    1
last_page   2
next_page_url   "http://blabla.de/test?page=2"
path    "http://blabla.de/test"
per_page    3
prev_page_url   
to  3
total   5
```

You can clearly see that there is a total of 5 items ( and thats true ), and there are 2 pages. Thats also true cause I've set the pagination to paginate(3).

If I output the links in my blade I get something like this:

[image]

But if I click on "2" - to get to the last page, I don't know why but the links change immediately to 1-7.

[image]

So before I want to change the pagination link, I get the right amound of items, but if I change to ?page=2, I get all the items in my table. I don't know why but maybe thats a mistake by laravel. I also tried it with laravel 5.3 ( currently 5.4 ) but got the same problem. If I look into the phpmyadmin query log and manually try the query out, I also get the perfect output. If I use ->get() instead of ->paginate(); I also get the right output. I have no clue anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Only use orWhere when you want to chain multiple where statements for your record fetching.

```
$users = \App\UserGroup::where('name', 'LIKE', '%Test%')->get();
```

I think the issue might come with the pagination.
I added this to get pagination working for my 2 records named Test and test

```
$users = \App\UserGroup::where('name', 'LIKE', '%Test%')->simplePaginate(1);
```

If you need to show the results on a view using blade, this might be helpful:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/pagination#displaying-pagination-results

Comment: I allready changed it from orWhere to where. But I still get all records back

Comment: Can you add that table structure so I can reproduce it ?

Comment: I've tried the query in phpmyadmin and it worked perfect.. Only with laravel it does'nt work. ` SELECT name FROM usergroups WHERE name LIKE '%Test%'  `